# How to wait for user input in an actor?

Tags: scala, akka

Is there any way to make an akka actor wait for user input? 
It seems to just read the command line by itself and keeps getting null.

EDIT: The problematic part of the code added, the problem is that the actor doesn't wait for the readline, rather it attempts to put a null into the variable num:

```
def chooser: Receive = {

    case ChooseRemote => {

        println("Available remotes:> ")
        paths.zipWithIndex.map{ case(x, i) => "num: " + i + " " + x }.foreach(println)

        println("Enter number:> ")

        try {
            val num = scala.io.StdIn.readLine().toInt

            clientActor ! LookupByLocation(paths(num))
        }
        catch {

            case _: Exception =>
            //context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(1.second, self, ChooseRemote)
        }
    }
    case Found(actor) => {

        context.become(menu(actor))

        context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(1.second, self, ChooseMenuItem)
    }
}

def receive: Receive = chooser
```

EDIT2: The problem manifests when I put: fork in run := true
in the build.sbt file.

Comment: I think you need to provide a _little_ more detail Code would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the sbt documentation:

> By default, the standard input of the sbt process is not forwarded to
>   the forked process. To enable this, configure the connectInput
>   setting: connectInput in run := true